# Overcoming lazy loading of tabControls and Combobxes

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, tabcontrol, lazy-evaluation

I am loading a few comboboxes with lots of strings (one has +70,000 values) before the main UI form is loaded in C#. I have the comboboxes in separate tabPages of a tabControl. I am doing this so that when the UI form is shown, there is no delays in showing up the tabs and comboboxes.

Now, the problem is that the first tabPage goes well and it shows up quickly. However, the other tabPages containing the other comboboxes take up to 10 seconds to get fully rendered and shown up.

I have tried to create the controls (comboboxes) using CreateControl before loading the UI form and it did not help. I understand that C# tabControls have this so called "lazy loading" behaviour. I wonder how I can overcome that "lazy" feature so that the comboboxes are created and rendered before the form is shown and when I change to other tab pages, there is no delays?

[now editted the tags - this is WinForms related.]

thanks,

Comment: I assume from the title that this is not winforms related, but it might be worth tagging your question with the UI framework in question (WinForms, WebForms, ASP.NET, Silverlight, MVC, etc) to eliminate confusion and point the question to those best suited to answer.

Comment: Just FYI, I [**just tested**](http://pastebin.com/SrqFttbN) a WPF ComboBox with 100,000 items and enabled [UI Virtualization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA) and the load time is 0.0053 seconds on my machine. Your best option here is to use the [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) and host a WPF ComboBox in your (existing?) winforms application. That's the only way to get anything good out of winforms.

Answer (score 0):

I guess threading will be the concept to overcome your problem. What you can do is start a new thread when form loads. Let the thread do the combo box filling or what ever work you required.

This thread will asynchronously update all the combo boxes. so there will be no delay when the form loads. The short example  of threads are provided below. I guess this would help you cent percent!

```
public class MyClass
{
    private volatile bool _KillThread;

    // This method will be called when the thread is started.
    public void DoWork()
    {
        while (!_KillThread)
        {
            //Do your work
        }

    }
    public void RequestStop()
    {
        _KillThread= true;
    }

}

static void MyFunction()
{
        MyClassworkerObject = new MyClass();
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.DoWork);

        // Start the thread.
        workerThread.Start();

        while (!workerThread.IsAlive);
             // allow the worker thread to do some work:
             Thread.Sleep(1);

        // Request that the worker thread stop itself:
        workerObject.RequestStop();

        //Wait untill the worker thread joins it self to main thread
        workerThread.Join();

}
```

You will find the similar example on MSDN as i had referred the code from there when i implemented it in my application a year back.

Cheeerss!!

Comment: Thanks for the comments, threading is not an option here because my problem is that the tabControl does not want to load the items into the combobox until the tab page wants to load them. I do not like my form/tab page to show up and the combobox still taking his time fetching items. What if user clicks on the combobox as soon as the page is shown?

I have no experience with WPF but worth trying.

thanks.